# How to disable loader in webpack 4

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

In previous versions of webpack, following configuration used to disable configured json-loader.

```
    require("!!file-loader?name=test.json!./assets/test.json");
```

In webpack 4, this doesn't seems to disable the default json-loader and still import json inline too. Is disabling loader still supported in webpack 4?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem. [Webpack 4 handles JSON now natively](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/releases/tag/v4.0.0).
The only way to overwrite the native JSON loader is to add the following to the rules:

```
{
  test: /\.json$/,
  loader: 'json-loader',
  type: "javascript/auto"
}
```

Comment: For me, I'm getting the below error. Do you have any idea on this?
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module.loaders[5] has an unknown property 'type'. These properties are valid:
   object { enforce?, exclude?, include?, issuer?, loader?, loaders?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, query?, resource?, resourceQuery?, compiler?, rules?, test?, use? }
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

Comment: @ABHILASHSB you need to define this within the property 'rules' which is an array.

Comment: @felixschorer As I understand the OP has asked how to skip the json parsing. I'm having the same issue. Applying 'json-loader' still parses the json to a js object.